# "react-dnd-html5-backend" has no exported member 'HTML5Backend'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to fix this error?

> 'react-dnd-html5-backend' has no exported member 'HTML5Backend'.

[image]

Comment: What is the react-dnd-html5-backend version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react-dnd-html5-backend named import works on `v11` or above.

If you encounter this error, please try to install `v11 or above`. The latest is `v14`

```
// install v11
npm install react-dnd-html5-backend@11

//or
// install latest v14
npm install react-dnd-html5-backend@latest
```

Comment: I installed     "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.0" and it is working now.

Comment: Great. please accept the answer if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting, I think all you need to do is follows

```js
import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend";
```

Comment: Then I will have another issue. import HTML5Backend from "react-dnd-html5-backend"; <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
...   S2322: Type '(manager: DragDropManager<any>) => HTML5Backend' is not assignable to type 'BackendFactory'.   Types of parameters 'manager' and 'manager' are incompatible.     Property 'getContext' is missing in type 'DragDropManager' but required in type 'DragDropManager<any>'.

Answer (score 0):

There are some inconsistencies in the book

The installation step mentions **version 4** of the backend

`yarn add react-dnd@14.0.1 react-dnd-html5-backend@4.0.0`

While the package.json for the finished project mentions **version 14**:

`"react-dnd-html5-backend": "^14.0.0"`

Basically there is a typo. You can always use package.json of finished version as a reference